# How to use BeautifulSoup find_previous with a condition or method?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Can find_previous be used to skip over tags that don't meet certain criteria?

```
for e in soup.select('p'):

   number = e.find_previous('b').isnumeric().get_text(strip=True)
```

**I am trying to find the previous tag with numeric text.**

adding the `.isnumeric()` method doesn't work.

`find_previous` has a parameter `text=` but that doesn't serve my purposes either.

For clarification, I need to pass over previous tags that aren't numeric until it reaches the tag that is numeric.

Answer (score 0):

`.isnumeric()` does not return a string. It returns a boolean value to let you know whether string is numeric or not.

You can use `.previous_sibling` and `.isnumeric()` method to achieve this.

See example, adapt as per your own code.

```
for e in soup.select('p'):
    prev_sibling = e.find_previous_sibling(text=lambda text: text.strip().isnumeric())
    if prev_sibling:
        number = prev_sibling.strip()
    else:
        number = None
```

Comment: I need find_previous to pass over a tag if it is not numeric

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the `.isnumeric()` method here, as it is a method of strings and not elements.

Corrected:

```
for e in soup.select('p'):
    number = e.find_previous('b').get_text(strip=True)
    if number.isnumeric():
        # do something
        pass
```